# Can anyone tell me why Smack's Presence.getMode() gives null in the case of available (online) contact?

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am working on a chat application on Android using XMPP. I retrieve the presence of RosterEntery when Presence object contains: available (Online). And I call  `presence.getMode()`  which returns **null**.

Can anyone tell me why `presence.getMode()` returns null in the case of online contact? And when Presence object contain : available (away) or (dnd) then Presence.getMode() works fine. Can anyone helps me about this?

Comment: Which XMPP library? 'getMode' is not a very descriptive function name.

Comment: i used  Presence prs = roster.getPresence(r.getUser().toString()); and if user is online then it gives me Available (online).                  but when i call Presence.Mode pm = prs.getMode(); then it gives me null . can anyone tell the reason behind this..

Answer (score 2):

the Smack library documentation states - "Returns the mode of the presence update, or null if the mode is not set. A null presence mode value is interpreted to be the same thing as Presence.Mode.available."

https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/Presence.html#getMode%28%29